# Accordion Closing Others

Tags: typescript, next.js

guys.

I'm building a NextJS project, and have a component that dynamically creates accordions on a page. I'm using typescript and having an issue with only one accordion being able to open at a time. How do I make sure that only the specific one clicked is being toggled?

Because currently, if there is an already active accordion, it will automatically close the previous one if I try to open another. I need it to allow people to open as many as they want, and not force the others to close when another is clicked.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaChevronDown, FaChevronUp } from 'react-icons/fa';

const faqList = () => {
  const faqArr = [
    { id: 1, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
    { id: 2, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
    { id: 3, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
    { id: 4, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
    { id: 5, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
    { id: 6, faqQuestion: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet?', answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu turpis molestie, dictum est a, mattis tellus. Sed dignissim, metus nec fringilla accumsan, risus sem sollicitudin lacus, ut interdum tellus elit sed risus. Maecenas eget condimentum velit, sit amet feugiat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.' },
  ];
  
  const [accordion, setActiveAccordion] = useState(-1);
  let toggleAccordion = (id: number) => {
    if (id === accordion) {
      setActiveAccordion(-1);
      return;
    }
    setActiveAccordion(id);
  }

  return (
 
    <>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-2'>
        {
          faqArr.map((FAQ, id) => 
            <div key={id} onClick={() => toggleAccordion(id)} className='gap-12 mt-2 mb-2 cursor-pointer ease-in'>
              <div className={accordion === id ? 'block' : ''}>
                <div className='flex justify-between pt-4 pr-6 pb-4 pl-6 border-2 m-2 rounded-xl text-black dark:text-white bg-white dark:bg-black relative z-auto dark:border-white'>
                  <h6 className="self-center font-bold">{FAQ.faqQuestion}</h6>
                    { accordion === id ? (
                      <FaChevronUp className='text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray self-center'  />
                    ) : (
                      <FaChevronDown className='text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray self-center' />
                    ) }
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={accordion === id ? 'block ease-in' : 'hidden ease-in'}>
                <p className='flex pt-8 pr-6 pb-4 pl-6 border-l-2 border-r-2 border-b-2 m-2 -mt-6 rounded-xl text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray z-0 rounded-tl-none rounded-tr-none border-[666]'>{FAQ.answer}</p>
              </div>
            </div>)
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default faqList
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your state is only allowing for a single id to be active at a time. You have to make it an array of ids and track that. Or better, add a separate component for the accordion content so it can track itself whether it is active/open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `accordion` state should be a array of active item index. So you can create a `Item` component to handle

```
const Item = ({ isOpen, FAQ, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={onClick}
            className="mt-2 mb-2 cursor-pointer gap-12 ease-in"
        >
            <div className={isOpen ? 'block' : ''}>
                <div className="relative z-auto m-2 flex justify-between rounded-xl border-2 bg-white pt-4 pr-6 pb-4 pl-6 text-black dark:border-white dark:bg-black dark:text-white">
                    <h6 className="self-center font-bold">{FAQ.faqQuestion}</h6>
                    {isOpen ? (
                        <FaChevronUp className="text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray self-center" />
                    ) : (
                        <FaChevronDown className="text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray self-center" />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={isOpen ? 'block ease-in' : 'hidden ease-in'}>
                <p className="text-k-dGray dark:text-k-lGray border-[666] z-0 m-2 -mt-6 flex rounded-xl rounded-tl-none rounded-tr-none border-l-2 border-r-2 border-b-2 pt-8 pr-6 pb-4 pl-6">
                    {FAQ.answer}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

and you can use it in `faqList`

```
const faqList = () => {
    const [accordion, setActiveAccordion] = useState([]);
    const toggleAccordion = (id: number) => {
        const newArray = accordion.includes(id) ? accordion.filter(i => i !== id) : [...accordion, id]
        setActiveAccordion(newArray)
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-2">
                {faqArr.map((FAQ, id) => (
                    <Item
                        key={id}
                        FAQ={FAQ}
                        isOpen={accordion.includes(id)}
                        onClick={() => toggleAccordion(id)}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```